# how do I stop a email validation pop-up from appearing when I click submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I managed to get a Javascript code that checks if the email is valid. So if you write aa@bb.com it's valid but if it's aa or aa@ or aa@bb. then it's not valid because it doesn't follow the pattern that I assign it to be in order to be valid. The thing is, I'm using Boostrap Form and if I click submit it accepts the email with the wrong pattern. How do I stop this? I still want to use Bootstrap because of the CSS.

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var name = $("#fullname").val();
  var email = $("#emailaddress").val();

  if (name == '' || email == '') {
    swal({
      title: "Empty Fields!",
      text: "Please check the missing fields",
      icon: "warning",
      button: "Ok, thank you",
    });
  } else if (email !== /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/) {
    swal({
      title: "Invalid Email!",
      text: "Please write a valid email address",
      icon: "warning",
      button: "Ok, thank you",
    });
  } else {
    swal({
      title: "Good job!",
      text: "You're subscriptions has been registered",
      icon: "success",
      button: "Awesome!",
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="box">
    <label for="fullname" class="form-tag">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" class="form-control" required/>
    <label for="emailaddress" class="form-tag">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control" required/>
    <div class="button">
      <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that the `button` is of type `submit`. Try changing it to `type="button"`.

Comment: Do you want it to only submit when the email address is valid?

Comment: Is your form possibly loaded dynamically? In that case `$("#submit").click(function(){...})` does not work and needs to be replaced with `$(document).on("click","#submit", function(){...})`

Comment: You can also use a `<form onsubmit="return checkForm()>"` and give true oder false back.

Answer (score 1):

- Check for user entered email correctness like this `!emailPattern.test(email)`
- If all are ok, manually submit the form
- Prevent the default submit event, as you want to validate the fields

```js
var emailPattern = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/

$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#fullname").val();
  var email = $("#emailaddress").val();

  if (name == '' || email == '') {
    console.log("Empty fields error");
  } else if (!emailPattern.test(email)) {
    console.log("Email pattern error");
  } else {
    console.log("Success");
    $('#testForm').submit(); // Here submit the form
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="testForm">
  <div class="box">
    <label for="fullname" class="form-tag">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="fullname" class="form-control" required/>
    <label for="emailaddress" class="form-tag">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control" required/>
    <div class="button">
      <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-lg">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work. However, I took the event.preventDefault(); and added it to my javascript code and now it's working. thank so much!! so the form is only submited if the email is valid according to the pattern. I only have one more problem. now when the form is submitted a pop up appear sayng "success" but it's only for one second. how do I keep it there for longer time or until the user clicks outside of the pop up?

Comment: Are you using any library to show popup? anyways you need to remove timer function on that popup which closes it.

Comment: I didn't get, how above solution not worked for you? You should validate pattern like that only. Did you solve that in any other way?

Comment: check my answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

`HTML5` has good (and supported) browser side validation on submit for `<input>` types like email.
And you used it

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="emailaddress" class="form-control" required/>
```

The problem is `<button type="submit">`

`Html` validation needs `<input type="submit">` because `<button>` is only empty decoration, not a handler. With `<input type="submit">` html checks the inserted value and if required field is blank or if `email` is not an email address it will not be submitted,

`JavaScript` reads `type="submit"` - so, let's move on to submit when it asks!
For `javascript` change `button type` or give a `name="check"` instead of type - `button` doesn't need any type

---

you may add css colours for `css validation` (keep the order)

```
input:invalid{ background: red}
input:invalid:focus{ background: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did. Thank you all for your help!

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var name = $("#fullname").val();
    var email = $("#emailaddress").val();
    var emailPattern = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
   
    if(name == '' || email == ''){
        swal({
            title: "Empty Fields!",
            text: "Please check the missing fields",
            icon: "warning",
            button: "Ok, thank you",
        });  
    }
    else if(!emailPattern.test(email)){
        swal({
            title: "Invalid Email!",
            text: "Please write a valid email address",
            icon: "warning",
            button: "Ok, thank you",
        }); 
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        swal({
            title: "Good job!",
            text: "You're subscriptions has been registered",
            icon: "success",
            button: "Awesome!",
        });
        $('#testForm').submit();
    };
});
```

Comment: `!emailPattern.test(email)` Actually this is the main part to stop form from submitting untill user enters a vaild email, which I mentioned in my answer.  Even with event.preventDefault also it works. Would you mind, accept my answer as that helped :)